# Find the width of the widest line of text in a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

In iOS 6 and lower, I can use `– sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`, but it has been deprecated in iOS 7.

In Apple documentation, it says to use `– boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` instead.

How would I use it though to get the width of text with UILineBreakModeWordWrap?

Comment: What part don't you understand? Did you try using the `boundingRect...` method?

Answer (score 0):

Pass an `NSString` into this method and it will return the height and width for it. You will need to set the max height and width in `boundingRectWithSize` to fit your needs.

```
- (CGSize)sizeOfText:(NSString*)text{

NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]}];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){yourMaxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];

return CGSizeMake(rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
 }
```

Comment: FYI - the last line can simply be `return rect.size;`.